# How to start up with JSF and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I have started learning JSF from JavaServer Faces 2.0 The Complete Reference.
Sadly there is no reference regarding how to set up JSF with Eclipse Indigo and all the information I could find is either dated or inaccurate.

I downloaded the JSF Library from [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) . I know that I can simply put this library in the WEB-INF/lib but I know that there is a method to link these two together. What am I missing?

Comment: Check this out: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[jsf]` tag which you've put on the question. In the popbox which appears, click the *info* link. At the bottom you can find some links to several decent tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

One i thing i would definitely recommend is this book:

Core Java Server Faces

[http://www.amazon.com/Core-JavaServer-Faces-David-Geary/dp/0137012896/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322777640&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896)

I actually just finished reading the newest edition and the book is so thorough. Everything from setting up your workbench to sending emails, persistence and Web Services. The authors use Eclipse as their IDE choice (cant recall which version though). Highly recommended read for a JSF dev!